# Avoidance of this.foo inside an object?

Tags: javascript

In my object I need to use this.foo like 50 times all over the place. I think it looks really ugly and unprofessional. I've tried using a closure but then I can't figure out how to call functions inside the closure from outside the closure.

```
function worker(input) {
    return {
        foo: "Hello World!",
        work: function () {
            alert(foo); // FAIL
            alert(this.foo); // !FAIL but ugly
        };
    }
}
```

One or two this.foo is fine but they are all over the place. Is there a way around this.foo?

Comment: This is how objects works in js. You could define a global variable, but this would be much more ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scope the reference to within the function and use a property getter and setter for `foo`:

```
function worker(input) {
  var foo = "Hello World!";

  return {
    get foo() {
        return foo;
    },
    set foo(v) {
        foo = v;
    },
    work: function () {
        alert(foo);
    }
  };
}
```

Why do you think that `this.foo` is 'ugly'?

Comment: This is one way, but to me it's definetly a lot more confusing than this.foo.

Comment: A caveat here is that the local variable does not get updated when the property is updated. You'd need a getter/setter: http://jsfiddle.net/ATsCm/.

Comment: this (pun intended) is why i think its ugly http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l493/powerfulcrunch/this.png

Answer (score 0):

You can alias it inside the function, there isn't really much point in my opinion.  I see nothing unprofessional about `this.foo`, and indeed it adds a great deal of readability.  It's a complaint I've head from C++ programmers before, having to reference `this` or `self` in other languages, but it is common.

```
    work: function () {
        // I wouldn't actually do this
        // I'd prefer just to use this.foo
        fooalias = this.foo;
        alert(fooalias);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no way to avoid this which isn't even more ugly than using `this.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function worker(input){ var t;
    return t = {
        foo: "Hello World!",
        work: function () {
            alert(t.foo); // less or more ugly, you decide :)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another version, which you shouldn't use:

```
function worker(){ var t={};
    with(t){
      t.foo = "Hello World!";
      t.work = function (){ alert(t.foo); }
    };
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `work` functions argument to pass it:

```
function worker(input) {
    return {
        foo: "Hello World!",
        work: function (foo) {
            alert(this.foo);
        }
    }
}

var f = worker('hello');
f.work(); // Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving this "problem" with a closure is easy:

```
function worker(input) {
    // Declare 'foo'
    var foo = "Hello World!";
    // Return closure
    return function () {
        alert(foo); // WIN
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var f = worker(myInput);
f(); // alerts "Hello World!"
```